# How to include Octave .la files?

Tags: c++, gcc, octave

I copied only the Octave lib and include folders from the original build folders and pasted into another (toolbox) folder. The toolbox folder has C++ code that has embedded Octave functions. The LD flags and C flags for compiling the code are-

`LD flags- "-L/path/to/lib -loctave -L/path/to/lib -loctinterp -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/lib/folder"`

`I flags- "-I/usr/include/scilab -I/path/include/octave-4.0.3 -I/path/include/octave-4.0.3/octave/"`

When I compile the C++ code, I get the error

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/home/fossee/Desktop/FSOIToolbox/thirdparty/linux/lib/x64/octave/4.0.3/liboctave.la' was moved.`
libtool: link: warning: library `/home/fossee/Desktop/FSOIToolbox/thirdparty/linux/lib/x64/octave/4.0.3/liboctinterp.la' was moved.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liboctave.la
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liboctinterp.la
```

I understand the issue is due to copying the lib files.

1. How do I include .la files in the flags so that the error is resolved for my system?
2. I need this code to work on any system. How do I include the Octave lib and include folders in the toolbox thirdparty folder such that it works on any system. When I go through the `liboctave.la` file, the paths in the file refer to my system. I need to make this general.

The source code is available here- https://github.com/shamikam/FOSSEE_Scilab_Octave_Interface_Toolbox

The Octave files are in `thirdparty` folder.

Comment: Hm the file endings are senseless to me. Aren't they usually `.so` ?

Comment: Octave source files are interpreted (or JIT-compiled), you don't include them in a C/C++ project or link to them - you need an Octave runtime.

Comment: the .la files are just text files and include the original path before the move. Open it with a text editor and have a look! This is a common point to struggle and not related to octave. I'm sure you'll find some great explanations when googling for "libtool .la seems to be moved"

Comment: `.la` files are not in fact libraries. They're description files that `libtool` uses to refer to libraries in the build process, and you can't copy them around without messing up.

Comment: Yes, I get that .la files cannot be copied. Let me rephrase my question. How do I build Octave libraries and include them in my project such that they can be used on any system? The path in .la files should not create a problem.